# Azure DocumentDB: Time-bound resource token remains valid after expiration time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm facing a strange problem in `DocumentDb`.
I created a user and permission for manipulating a specific collection. Then I requested a resource token with a limited validity for that user. I did this by setting `ResourceTokenExpirySeconds` to say 10 seconds. To test it, I waited enough in order the token got expired. However, Azure accepted subsequent requests using that (supposedly expired) token.

Considering the following code, it is expected the this line fails but it doesn't:

```
UserPermissionExample.TestToken(10, 15);
```

And here is `UserPermissionExample` implementation:

```
public class UserPermissionExample 
{
    const string endPoint = "https://[ENDPOINT].documents.azure.com";
    const string masterKey = "[PRIMARY-KEY]";
    const string dbName = "test-db";
    const string testUserId = "test-user";
    const string collName = "test-coll";

    public static async Task TestToken(int validity, int wait)
    {
        // Get a time-bound token
        string token = await GetToken(validity /*seconds*/);

        // Wait enough so the token gets expired
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(wait));

        // Try to add a document with the expired token. It is expected to fail:
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPoint), token);
        await client.CreateDocumentAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(dbName, collName),
            new { name = "A test document" });
    }

    static async Task<string> GetToken(int tokenValiditySeconds)
    {
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPoint), masterKey);
        ResourceResponse<Database> db = await UpsertDb(client);
        ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> collection = await UpsertCollection(client, db);

        var userUrl = UriFactory.CreateUserUri(dbName, "testuser");
        var user = await client.UpsertUserAsync(db.Resource.SelfLink, new User() { Id = testUserId });

        var permission =
            await client.UpsertPermissionAsync(
                user.Resource.SelfLink,
                new Permission()
                {
                    Id = "PersmissionForTestUser",
                    PermissionMode = PermissionMode.All,
                    ResourceLink = collection.Resource.SelfLink,
                },
                new RequestOptions() { ResourceTokenExpirySeconds = tokenValiditySeconds });

        permission =
            await client.ReadPermissionAsync(
                permission.Resource.SelfLink,
                new RequestOptions() { ResourceTokenExpirySeconds = tokenValiditySeconds });

        return permission.Resource.Token;
    }

    static async Task<ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection>> UpsertCollection(DocumentClient client, ResourceResponse<Database> db)
    {
        ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> collection = null;
        try
        {
            collection = await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(dbName, collName));
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException ex)
        {
            if (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                collection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(db.Resource.SelfLink, new DocumentCollection() { Id = collName });
            }
        }

        return collection;
    }

    static async Task<ResourceResponse<Database>> UpsertDb(DocumentClient client)
    {
        ResourceResponse<Database> db = null;
        try
        {
            db = await client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(dbName));
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException ex)
        {
            if (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                db = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database() { Id = dbName });
            }
        }

        return db;
    }
}
```

**PS: I'm using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB version="1.11.4".**

**Update: I found that Azure starts checking token expiry from 5 minutes after token issue time ! Then it rejects the token. So prior to this period, no matter token is expired or not, Azure accepts it!**

Comment: Since you figured out the issue, please post as a proper answer, rather than an edit to your question. That way, this question can be properly closed out.

Comment: @DavidMakogon It isn't an answer. Still I have objection regarding for the grace period.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that DocumentDB has some slack in the token expiry to allow for potential clock skews in the client or server. Because of this tokens have a "grace period" after their real expiry time. The allowed clock skew is in the tune of 5 minutes which is why you see the behaviour that you do.

Is there a particular reason you're creating a token that should be valid only for 10 seconds?

Full disclosure: I work at DocumentDB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First, is this behavior documented? Second, the reason for this requirement is that I want to delegate update of a particular document or collection to another application.

Comment: It is not only DocumentDB also. Clock skew is so common, that for example IoT Hubs have an identical 5 minute grace period.

Comment: @juunas I see. It seems that this skew comes from JWT library used by Azure. Do you know any documentation stating this specifically?

Comment: If my mobile device has wrong time (time difference is more/less  5 minute than actual time), the cosmosDb client never works. Can I resolve it anyways?